# Getting AD users having a specific keyword within description field in AD

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I want to get all of those users starting with a specific keywords in AD User Description field using PowerShell.
Keyword: Could not execute powershell

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=contoso, DC=contoso, DC=local' - Properties Description | select -expand name,distinguishedname,description  | Export-Csv -path C:\description.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Last Update :

```
 Get-ADUser -Properties Description -Filter 'Description -like "*Could not  execute powershell*"' -SearchBase 'OU=contoso, DC=contoso, DC=local' | 
select name,distinguishedname,description  | 
Export-Csv -path C:\description2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an easy task using the -filter option that you can use with `get-aduser`.

For more info how to filter: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617241.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Under the filter bit

```
 Get-ADUser -Properties Description -Filter {Description -like $Description} -SearchBase 'OU=contoso, DC=contoso, DC=local' | select Name, DistinguishedName, Description | Export-Csv -path C:\description2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I got erro like Get-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'Filter' is specified more than once. To provide multiple values to parameters that can accept multiple values, use the array syn
tax. For example, "-parameter value1,value2,value3".

Comment: @Arbelac See my update, add your searchbase if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply filter for Description:

```
Get-ADUser -Properties Description -Filter 'Description -like "*Could not execute powershell*"' -SearchBase 'OU=contoso, DC=contoso, DC=local'
```

Comment: That won't run, You need to remove the -expand part.

Comment: In my case I had to run with Get-ADUser -Properties Description -Filter 'Description -like "*Could not execute powershell*"' to look up for whole forest. Worked as expected and the idea is great :)